# Finding a index of a vector with specific value

Tags: c++

I'm doing codility test and one of them is (my solution is at the bottom of this post):
**Task description**

A small frog wants to get to the other side of a river. The frog is currently located at position 0, and wants to get to position X. Leaves fall from a tree onto the surface of the river.

You are given a non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers representing the falling leaves. A[K] represents the position where one leaf falls at time K, measured in seconds.

The goal is to find the earliest time when the frog can jump to the other side of the river. The frog can cross only when leaves appear at every position across the river from 1 to X. You may assume that the speed of the current in the river is negligibly small, i.e. the leaves do not change their positions once they fall in the river.

For example, you are given integer X = 5 and array A such that:

A[0] = 1
  A[1] = 3
  A[2] = 1
  A[3] = 4
  A[4] = 2
  A[5] = 3
  A[6] = 5
  A[7] = 4

In second 6, a leaf falls into position 5. This is the earliest time when leaves appear in every position across the river.

Write a function:

```
int solution(int X, vector<int> &A);
```

that, given a non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers and integer X, returns the earliest time when the frog can jump to the other side of the river.

If the frog is never able to jump to the other side of the river, the function should return −1.

For example, given X = 5 and array A such that:

A[0] = 1
  A[1] = 3
  A[2] = 1
  A[3] = 4
  A[4] = 2
  A[5] = 3
  A[6] = 5
  A[7] = 4

the function should return 6, as explained above.

Assume that:

```
    N and X are integers within the range [1..100,000];
    each element of array A is an integer within the range [1..X].
```

Complexity:

```
    expected worst-case time complexity is O(N);
    expected worst-case space complexity is O(X), beyond input storage (not counting the storage required for input arguments).
```

Elements of input arrays can be modified.

```
**My solution:**
int solution(int X, vector<int> &A) {
    // write your code in C++11
    auto iter = find(A.cbegin(), A.cend(), X);
    if (iter != A.cend())
    {
        return distance(A.cbegin(),iter);
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

None-the-less, after submitting this solution to codility, I'm getting reply that this is incorrect solution and that it gives wrong answer. Could somebody please tell me where I've got it wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: I don't think anyone will go through reading your question when it's formatted like that.

Comment: @piezol sorry about that, I've corrected the formatting

Comment: Well, your solution only finds, when the first leave falls at the position of X
Your task is to find out the answer to question "when will leaves fall at ALL positions between 1..X".

Comment: I think you miss that there might be several leaves falling at some time before time X. Or not. And that when you are at leave #1, you have to wait for leave #2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution i can come up with.
Note that c++ is not my favourite language and the code is laughable (and most likely it's not the optimal solution), but hey, it works and it's simple.

```
using namespace std;
int solution(int X, vector<int> &a){
  set<int> filled = set<int>();
  int time_taken = -1;
  for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
    if(a[i] > 0 && a[i] <= X){
      filled.insert(a[i]);
      if(filled.size() == X) return i;
    }
  } 
  return -1;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is much better than mine ;) and your actually works.

Comment: I would like people, who downvoted me, to provide a better solution, so i could learn something as well....

Comment: I wouldn't count on that. Those are lame asses who instead of providing valid and constructive input/criticism only downvote. Forget about those ticks. And change t to D in last word of my last but one sentence;)

Comment: I've actually wanted to know the better solution, because according to task description, problem is O(n), my solution is O(n*log(n)) and uses old-fashioned loop and uses additional memory for a set. I'm not accusing anyone of being asshole.